# Recognize if object is completely or partially visible with Bing/Azure Cognitive API

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

Wondering, how do I recognize if an image contains a specific object and this object is completely visible (not partially).

[Cognitive Services Computer Vision API](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/Computer-Vision-API/documentation) provides set of tags and description of the image I send, however, there is no information if object is completely or partially represented.

My goal is to have a service that I can upload a picture of, say, car, and get information is it a full car visible or just part of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the Computer Vision API is currently unable to perform such a function.

The tags returned do have a 'score' which represents the confidence that this item is in the image. You may find there's some correlation between the confidence and how much of the item is in the image, but you'd need to run some experiments to see how well it matches up. If the object is obscured too much, it may not even detect it all.

Feel free to drop a suggestion on our [User Voice](https://cognitive.uservoice.com/forums/430309-computer-vision), if you think this would be a useful feature.

Comment: https://cognitive.uservoice.com/forums/430309-computer-vision/suggestions/18585289-recognize-if-object-on-picture-is-displayed-comple